What is the cause of this intermittent slow query when counting rows over a single indexed text column in PostgreSQL?
I have a table with 2,395,015 rows, where a TEXT column has one of three values and is never NULL. I have intermittent query performance issues when counting the number of rows where the value matches most (>99%) of the rows. I want to fix this performance problem. These queries must return exact counts, so I can't use approximate counts.
corpus=# \d metadata
                             Table "public.metadata"
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |    Default
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------
 id            | text                        |           | not null |
 priority      | integer                     |           | not null | 10
 media_type    | text                        |           | not null |
 modified      | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
 processed     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 status        | text                        |           | not null | 'QUEUED'::text
 note          | text                        |           |          |
 content       | text                        |           |          |
 resolved      | text                        |           |          |
 response_time | integer                     |           |          |
 luid          | integer                     |           | not null |
 jamo_date     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 audit_path    | text                        |           |          |
Indexes:
    "metadata_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "metadata_id_idx" btree (id)
    "metadata_luid_idx" btree (luid)
    "metadata_modified_idx" btree (modified DESC)
    "metadata_processed_idx" btree (processed DESC)
    "metadata_status_idx" btree (status)
Check constraints:
    "media_type_ck" CHECK (media_type = ANY (ARRAY['text/json'::text, 'text/yaml'::text]))
    "status_ck" CHECK (status = ANY (ARRAY['QUEUED'::text, 'PROCESSED'::text, 'ERROR'::text]))
Foreign-key constraints:
    "metadata_luid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (luid) REFERENCES concept(luid) ON DELETE CASCADE

corpus=#

I have some simple queries that count the number of rows matching one of the three status codes (QUEUED, PROCESSED, ERROR). There are 0 rows matching QUEUED, 9,794 matching ERROR, and 2,385,221 matching PROCESSED. When I run an identical query against each of these status codes, I usually get a result set promptly:
corpus=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metadata WHERE status='QUEUED';
                                                                          QUERY PLAN

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1947.17..1947.18 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.935..2.936 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Index Only Scan using metadata_status_idx on public.metadata  (cost=0.43..1915.97 rows=12480 width=0) (actual time=2.932..2.933 rows=0 loops=1)
         Output: status
         Index Cond: (metadata.status = 'QUEUED'::text)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.734 ms
 Execution Time: 2.988 ms
(8 rows)

corpus=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metadata WHERE status='ERROR';
                                                                             QUERY PLAN

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1184.19..1184.20 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1484.763..1484.764 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Index Only Scan using metadata_status_idx on public.metadata  (cost=0.43..1165.26 rows=7569 width=0) (actual time=4.235..1484.029 rows=9794 loops=1)
         Output: status
         Index Cond: (metadata.status = 'ERROR'::text)
         Heap Fetches: 9584
 Planning Time: 0.072 ms
 Execution Time: 1484.786 ms
(8 rows)

corpus=#

corpus=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metadata WHERE status='PROCESSED';
                                                                                          QUERY PLAN

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=261398.83..261398.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=741.319..749.026 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Gather  (cost=261398.62..261398.83 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=741.309..749.020 rows=3 loops=1)
         Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=260398.62..260398.63 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=735.099..735.100 rows=1 loops=3)
               Output: PARTIAL count(*)
               Worker 0: actual time=730.871..730.872 rows=1 loops=1
               Worker 1: actual time=733.435..733.436 rows=1 loops=1
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using metadata_status_idx on public.metadata  (cost=0.43..257903.37 rows=998100 width=0) (actual time=0.065..700.529 rows=795074 loops=3)
                     Output: status
                     Index Cond: (metadata.status = 'PROCESSED'::text)
                     Heap Fetches: 747048
                     Worker 0: actual time=0.060..702.980 rows=670975 loops=1
                     Worker 1: actual time=0.076..686.946 rows=1010099 loops=1
 Planning Time: 0.085 ms
 Execution Time: 749.068 ms
(18 rows)

corpus=#

But occasionally, count for the PROCESSED rows takes an excessive amount of time (sometimes several minutes):
corpus=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metadata WHERE status='PROCESSED';
                                                                                           QUERY PLAN

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=261398.83..261398.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=30019.273..30019.336 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Gather  (cost=261398.62..261398.83 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=30019.261..30019.326 rows=3 loops=1)
         Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=260398.62..260398.63 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=29967.734..29967.735 rows=1 loops=3)
               Output: PARTIAL count(*)
               Worker 0: actual time=29939.915..29939.916 rows=1 loops=1
               Worker 1: actual time=29944.395..29944.395 rows=1 loops=1
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using metadata_status_idx on public.metadata  (cost=0.43..257903.37 rows=998100 width=0) (actual time=75.385..29931.795 rows=795074 loops=3)
                     Output: status
                     Index Cond: (metadata.status = 'PROCESSED'::text)
                     Heap Fetches: 747151
                     Worker 0: actual time=128.857..29899.156 rows=916461 loops=1
                     Worker 1: actual time=28.609..29905.708 rows=854439 loops=1
 Planning Time: 421.203 ms
 Execution Time: 30019.440 ms
(18 rows)

corpus=#

While the above query is running slowly, I am able to query the same table for either of the other two codes, and those queries return within 1 second. I have looked for table locks (there are none). This happens even when there are no other queries or table inserts running.

What are the possible causes for these intermittent slow queries?
What additional debugging can I try to get some more information about these slow queries?
Are there any relevant server settings?
Is there a more efficient way to index / code these columns (e.g., should I use a CHAR(1)), or even a SMALLINT? If so, what index should be used for the column?

If I use a CHAR(1), is there any difference between the following constraints:

ALTER TABLE jgi_metadata ADD CONSTRAINT status_code_ck CHECK (status_code = ANY (ARRAY['Q'::char(1), 'P'::char(1), 'E'::char(1)]));

ALTER TABLE jgi_metadata ADD CONSTRAINT status_code_ck CHECK (status_code IN ('Q', 'P', 'E'));

Could a partial index be used for this column, even though it is never NULL?

Should I split the PROCESSED off into a boolean column, and then use the status column only for the other codes and make it nullable with a partial index?


This is PostgreSQL 11 with default settings, running on Linux.
Other things I have tried:

Increased the work_mem to 100MB (via postgresql.conf). No change in performance.
I tried creating a partial index on the status column.


Update: I have discovered that this performance issue has nothing to do with the status column, but rather the size of the table itself, as the following 2-minute query shows:
corpus=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metadata;
                                                                                            QUERY PLAN

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=196398.52..196398.53 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=118527.897..118554.762 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Gather  (cost=196398.30..196398.51 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=118522.165..118554.756 rows=3 loops=1)
         Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=195398.30..195398.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=118491.043..118491.044 rows=1 loops=3)
               Output: PARTIAL count(*)
               Worker 0: actual time=118475.143..118475.144 rows=1 loops=1
               Worker 1: actual time=118476.110..118476.111 rows=1 loops=1
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using metadata_status_idx on public.metadata  (cost=0.43..192876.13rows=1008870 width=0) (actual time=71.797..118449.265 rows=809820 loops=3)
                     Output: status
                     Heap Fetches: 552630
                     Worker 0: actual time=75.877..118434.476 rows=761049 loops=1
                     Worker 1: actual time=104.872..118436.647 rows=745770 loops=1
 Planning Time: 592.040 ms
 Execution Time: 118554.839 ms
(17 rows)

corpus=#

This seems to be very similar to other questions now, so I am trying mitigation strategies from this answer:

VACUUM ANALYZE metadata; First COUNT(*) after this took 5 seconds, subsequent counts took 190ms.

Other thoughts:

Would it help if the status column were split off into its own table, with a foreign key into the metadata table?

Note: I am becoming convinced that this question is a duplicate of several other questions here:

PostgreSQL extremely slow counts
count(*) queries are too slow even with an index only scan
Why are some count queries so slow?
Optimizing select count result in Postgresql
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449716/postgres-why-does-select-count-take-so-long
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916633/if-postgresql-count-is-always-slow-how-to-paginate-complex-queries
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table-in-postgresql/7945274#7945274

This answer may hold the best solution for this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/2074605

As requested, here is a query plan analysis with buffers:
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metadata;

                                                                                           QUERY PLAN

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=80771.95..80771.96 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=26711.481..26716.494 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   Buffers: shared hit=293915 read=19595 dirtied=282 written=12
   ->  Gather  (cost=80771.73..80771.94 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=26711.203..26716.488 rows=3 loops=1)
         Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=293915 read=19595 dirtied=282 written=12
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=79771.73..79771.74 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=26565.622..26565.623 rows=1 loops=3)
               Output: PARTIAL count(*)
               Buffers: shared hit=293915 read=19595 dirtied=282 written=12
               Worker 0: actual time=26530.890..26530.891 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=105264 read=6760 dirtied=145 written=5
               Worker 1: actual time=26530.942..26530.942 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=84675 read=7529 dirtied=46 written=2
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using metadata_status_idx on public.metadata  (cost=0.43..77241.05 rows=1012275 width=0) (actual time=42.254..26529.232 rows=809820 loops=3)
                     Output: status
                     Heap Fetches: 17185
                     Buffers: shared hit=293915 read=19595 dirtied=282 written=12
                     Worker 0: actual time=59.291..26494.376 rows=815113 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=105264 read=6760 dirtied=145 written=5
                     Worker 1: actual time=31.165..26484.729 rows=1036972 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=84675 read=7529 dirtied=46 written=2
 Planning Time: 98.400 ms
 Execution Time: 26716.529 ms
(25 rows)


EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) would've been useful I think.

@StanislavBashkyrtsev Thank you for the suggestion, I added that information to the question. That form of EXPLAIN is new to me.

So 26s to read (19595+7529)*8/1000=216 MB from disk. You can keep playing with this and see how much the timing depends on the pages read.

My guess is that sometimes a lot of the heap pages are buffered, and the queries run quickly. Other times the buffer is loaded with other pages, and so you end up waiting to read the data from the disk.
There are 2 problems with this kind of querying:

Even though the query is covered by the index, it has to fetch heap tuples because of MVCC - it doesn't know which of the index records are visible for the current tx. This could be improved if a lot of pages end up in the Visibility Map. But if you constantly update records on old pages, it won't hold for long.
Regardless of the optimizations, this is just bad querying. The cardinality of your column is very low. If the query needs to inspect almost all the data, then it won't be fast on big tables. Maybe you should keep track of the counts in a separate table and update those counts when the rows in the main table is modified.

Postgres keeps statistics for the columns, including the histograms of how many rows of each value to expect. If approximate statistics is enough for you, you can just query pg_stats. Another approach could be to use sampling. It's also an approximation. But if you need exact numbers, then you should consider doing something more sophisticated and keeping the statistics in a separate table yourself.

Based on my testing described in my revised question and advice from answers to similar questions (see here and here), I have implemented the following changes:

Created a partial index on the status column. CREATE INDEX status_not_processed_idx ON metadata (status) WHERE status<>'PROCESSED';
Vacuumed table. VACUUM ANALYZE metadata;
Adjusted auto-vacuum settings on table. ALTER TABLE metadata SET (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0, autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0,  autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 10000, autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 10000);
Created a fast_row_count(table_name) function based on the method described here:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fast_count_rows(table_name text)
RETURNS bigint
AS $$
SELECT
(
  CASE WHEN c.reltuples < 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN c.relpages = 0 THEN float8 '0'
       ELSE c.reltuples / c.relpages END * (pg_catalog.pg_relation_size(c.oid) / pg_catalog.current_setting('block_size')::int)
)::bigint
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
  WHERE c.oid = CONCAT('public.',table_name)::regclass
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;

corpus=> SELECT fast_count_rows('metadata');
 fast_count_rows
-----------------
         2192335


Avoid using COUNT(*) or counts on PROCESSED value:

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW metadata_queue_statistics AS
SELECT
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'QUEUED'::text) AS queued,
  fast_count_rows('metadata') - COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = ANY (ARRAY ['QUEUED'::text, 'ERROR'::text])) AS completed,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'ERROR'::text) AS failed,
  fast_count_rows('metadata') AS total
FROM metadata
;

corpus=> SELECT * FROM metadata_queue_statistics;
queued | failed | completed |  total
--------+--------+-----------+---------
  19258 |  11372 |   2398829 | 2429459
(1 row)

The initial performance test looked promising (422ms) but subsequent testing of this approach yielded the same performance issue:
corpus=> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) SELECT * FROM metadata_queue_statistics;

                        QUERY PLAN

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=127854.78..127855.29 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=76853.872..76853.872 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*) FILTER (WHERE (metadata.status = 'QUEUED'::text)), (fast_count_rows('metadata'::text) - count(*) FILTER (WHERE (metadata.status = ANY ('{QUEUED,ERROR}'::text[])))), count(*) FILTER (WHERE (metadata.status = 'ERROR'::text)), fast_count_rows('metadata'::text)
   Buffers: shared hit=295240 read=26638 dirtied=383 written=18
   ->  Index Only Scan using metadata_status_idx on public.metadata  (cost=0.43..91412.89 rows=2429459 width=9) (actual time=0.071..76432.532 rows=2429459 loops=1)
         Output: metadata.status
         Heap Fetches: 28878
         Buffers: shared hit=295234 read=26638 dirtied=383 written=18
 Planning Time: 124.091 ms
 Execution Time: 76853.911 ms
(9 rows)

I will not to mark this as the answer for my question because the performance problem persisted. I'm leaving this here as an example of a failed solution.
Also attempted:

Increased shared_buffers in postgresql.conf from default 128MB to 2GB. (no significant change in query performance)

